# Why doesn't didSet work?

Tags: swift, swift-structs

In many examples of `didSet` I see on SO, this code will return `0`, however, I can't get it to return anything other than the original value. What am I doing wrong?

**Swift**

```
struct Circle {
    var radius: Double {
        didSet {
            if radius < 0 {
                radius = 0
            }
        }
    }
}

var circ = Circle(radius: -25)

print(circ.radius)
```

**Output**

```
-25
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`didSet` isn't called during initialization, only afterwards. If you want to validate data during initialization, your initializer should do it.

If you add:

```
circ.radius = -50
print(circ.radius)
```

you'll see it working as you'd expect, and the output will be `0.0`.

Answer (score 15):

You can make sure `didSet` in the `init`, if you put it in a `defer` statement. Also works in `deinit`.

```
class Circle {
    var radius: Double {
       didSet {
          if radius < 0 {
             radius = 0
          }
       }
    }

    init(radius: Double) {
        defer { self.radius = radius }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

As written by Paul in the comments, property observers `didSet` and `willSet` are not called during value initialization.

If you want to call them for a value also on initialization, you could add a function call to re-set the `radius` property after it has been initially set in the initializer:

```
struct Circle {
    var radius: Double {
        didSet {
            if radius < 0 {
                radius = 0
            }
        }
    }

    init(radius: Double) {
        self.radius = radius
        setRadius(radius) // <-- this will invoke didSet
    }

    mutating func setRadius(radius: Double) {
        self.radius = radius
    }
}

var circ = Circle(radius: -25)

print(circ.radius) // 0.0
```

Comment: Just curious, why do we need the first `self.radius = radius` in `init` when the second declaration in `setRadius` is identical, in addition to actually triggering `didSet`?

Comment: Try removing it and you'll be prompted with a quite telling error: "`'self'` used before all stored properties are initialized". Attempting to access the (`mutating`) function `setRadius(radius:)` is equivalent to attempting to use `self`, which is not allowed until `self` has been fully initialized.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use lazy and init(radius ....

```
struct Circle {
    lazy var radius: Double = 0.0 {
        didSet {
            print("didSet called")
            if radius < 0 {
                radius = 0
            }
        }
    }
    init(radius:Double) {
        self.radius = radius
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked best for my use case compared to the other suggestions above. Just wondering, why does this not work without lazy ?

Answer (score 0):

Use init for this:

```
struct Circle {
    var radius: Double

    init(radius: Double) {
        self.radius = radius < 0 ? 0 : radius
    }
}

var circ = Circle(radius: -25)

print(circ.radius)

0.0
```